# Why is restart_lsn not set, even on checkpoint - postgresql

Tags: replication, postgresql-10

> A logical slot will emit each change just once in normal operation.
>   The current position of each slot is persisted only at checkpoint, so
>   in the case of a crash the slot may return to an earlier LSN, which
>   will then cause recent changes to be resent when the server restarts.
>   Logical decoding clients are responsible for avoiding ill effects from
>   handling the same message more than once. Clients may wish to record
>   the last LSN they saw when decoding and skip over any repeated data or
>   (when using the replication protocol) request that decoding start from
>   that LSN rather than letting the server determine the start point

Quoted from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/logicaldecoding-explanation.html)

I'm implementing a logical (streaming) replication.

Thus far things are looking good but I'm unable to understand why restart_lsn entry is not changed.

i.e I do this..

```
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;
 slot_name |  plugin  | slot_type | datoid | database | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin | restart_lsn
-----------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------------
 pgx_test  | wal2json | logical   |  12641 | postgres | t      |      16045 |      |      8544916 | 2/B1BC5330
```

Insert 2/3 record

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_replication;
  pid  | usesysid |     usename     | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |          backend_start           | backend_xmin |   state   | sent_location | write_location | flush_location | replay_location | sync_priority | sync_state
-------+----------+-----------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------
 16315 |  1601109 | pgx_replication |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       50112 | 2019-03-11 17:33:18.150179+05:30 |              | streaming | 2/B1BCA0F8    |                |                |                 |             0 | async
```

The sent_location gets updated but not the restart_lsn, even though I ran a `checkpoint` command had set the `checkoint_timeout=1m` but still the replay_lsn does not change.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;
 slot_name |  plugin  | slot_type | datoid | database | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin | restart_lsn
-----------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------------
 pgx_test  | wal2json | logical   |  12641 | postgres | t      |      16315 |      |      8544916 | 2/B1BC5330
(1 row)
```

Any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

first we need to understand what exactly **restart_lsn** is...

**restart_lsn**:- The address (LSN) of oldest WAL which still might be required by the consumer of this slot and thus won't be automatically removed during checkpoints.

It is the definition from official postgres documentation.

or we can say that **restart_lsn** is the oldest LSN from which server must retain WAL changes,even after check point process because to facilitate logical decoding after server is restarted.

When publisher's server stops due to powerloss/something, after restarting the publisher server...output plugin try to decode changes from **restart_lsn point** in WAL so that transactions which are not yet committed at the time when server stopped are decoded from restart_lsn...so that logical replication process is not stopped....so restart_lsn helps to continue logical decoding without fail.

In your case when you try to insert many rows you will find restart_lsn will change after sometime....to new value